# How to render ImageBackground fullscreen inside a SafeAreaView with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I had a look on multiple answers but none works for me. I am looking to make the background image larger, so it could take all the screen. I put the ImageBackground tag inside the SafeAreaView and start styling it.

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
    <StatusBar />
    <ImageBackground resizeMode='cover' source={forrest} style={styles.bgImageView}>

        {/* Content */}
    </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I also tried to work with flex: 1 but it takes down the image...

```
  // Top view
  bgImageView: {
    padding: 20,
    // flex: 1, tried also this but does not work
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  },
```

If i give the safe area view a red color, it will color it. But the image, no matter if I replace it with a large one, it won't work

[image]

Comment: Put it in a View wrapping the SafeAreaScreen instead.

Comment: you mean wrap the safe area in a view, than the safe area should contain the image background tag? Like 1. View, 2. SafeAreaView, 3. ImageBackground?

Comment: I tried, but than the IOS status bar stop functioning...And the bottom space is not changed

Comment: removing the padding style worked, but only on the android. On iphone I have still a gap

Comment: That, or the ImageBackground component itself. Wrap the SafeAreaScreen with it.